# convert byte array avro to parquet

Tags: avro, parquet

I got byte array from below code

```
public static byte[] jsonToAvro(String json, Schema schema) throws IOException {
DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
GenericDatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, json);
Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(output, null);
Object datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
writer.write(datum, encoder);
encoder.flush();
output.close();
System.out.println("Serialization: " + output);
return output.toByteArray(); }
```

Here output.toByteArray() contain byte array of avro.

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:\\Users\\xyz\\workspace\\JasonToAvro\\src\\main\\java\\json\\avro\\test.avro"), avroByteArray)
File Avro_file = new File("C:\\Users\\xyz\\workspace\\JasonToAvro\\src\\main\\java\\json\\avro\\test.avro");

static void fromAvroToParquet( File avroFile  ) throws IOException{
GenericDatumReader<Object> greader = new GenericDatumReader<Object>();
FileReader<Object> fileReader = DataFileReader.openReader(avroFile, greader);
Schema avroSchema = fileReader.getSchema() ; //further code
```

when I am trying to convert it into file with .avro extension I am getting an error "Not an Avro data file".

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not an Avro data file
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader.openReader(DataFileReader.java:63)
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader.openReader(DataFileReader.java:42)
at json.avro.JasonToAvro.JasonToAvro.fromAvroToParquet(JasonToAvro.java:81)
at json.avro.JasonToAvro.JasonToAvro.main(JasonToAvro.java:39)
```

I am referring this blog http://avrotoparquet.blogspot.in/2014/09/convert-avro-file-to-parquet-format.html for avro to parquet conversion.Any other method for conversion are welcome.